# Copy/paste data into the previous column - VBA

Tags: copy-paste

I have columns "Current week" (col H) and "Previous week" (col G) both Headers being dinamic for each week (next week will be "Current Week" col I and "Previous week" - col H).
The thing is I need to copy the data from Current week to Previous week (column from left) each time I want run the report in order to have the hystoric data.

I found some codes but they are not working to copy data on the previous column.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937684/566169) contains what you're looking for. You want to copy the range with .Copy, then paste the values in the other column with .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues.

Comment: Yes but you need to take in cosnideration the location of Current week and Previous week is dinamicly. I order to simply I named the range for Current week as H1Range (Ex: H3:H16) and I need to copy the data to previous column which is G3:G16. I need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702798/excel-vba-copy-paste-to-next-empty-column/52702936 but with previous column

Comment: I was merely stating that you need to copy values, not references. How you reference them is up to you. What I often do is record a macro of what I want to do, and that will give me the code for it if I am unsure.

Comment: As I setuped the Current as named range I made it with this Range("H1Range").Offset(, -1).Copy. Thx for the help anyway, kindly appreciate it !